# backgroundColor não está funcionando no chrome (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, css

Bom-dia pessoal, estou fazendo um curso de jquery e ao fazer alguns testes com múltiplas declarações css o chrome executa a parte do backgroundColor, porem tanto no firefox e no ie funcionam sem problema, até procurei algum fiz ou coisa do tipo mas não encontrei nada, esse é a linha que estou usando:

```
.css({color:'blue', border:'1px solid blue', backgroundColor:'green'})
```

desde já agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia, tente assim:

```
 $("exemplo").css({"background-color": "green", "color":"blue", "border":"1px solid blue"});
```

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Comment: Obrigado, até imaginei tentar dessa forma mas não o fiz (erro meu), funcionou corretamente, obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou a resolver a sua questão de alguma forma, considere marcar a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, Teste desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").css({color:'blue', border:'1px solid blue', background-color:'green'});
});
```

Comment: obrigado por responder amigo, o exemplo é igual ao do colega abaixo.

Comment: me desculpe não tinha visto que já tinham respondido :/